# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin x \, dx = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin x \, dx$$
When I am doing the proof for this, why do i have to split it into 
$\int_{-\infty}^a \sin x \, dx + \int_a^\infty \sin x \, dx $? 
where a is a constant

Comment: The Cauchy Principal Value is $0$. But the improper integral does not converge.

Comment: I think you should ask why you need to break integral into two parts while you are testing for the existence of this improper integral?

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, as an improper Riemann integral it diverges.  Also, as a Lebesgue integral it diverges.  If mathematicians write an integral, it is generally one of these two.  So: anyone who claims the answer is zero should say what integral THEY are using.

Comment: @Gedgar It doesn't diverge as a Lebesgue Integral, but $\sin$ is a non measurable function at all. If you want to spli hairs using a non hausdorff topology you can also have convergence ;)

Comment: Paradoxical as it may seem, this is true in the sense of distributions. The portuguese mathematician J. Sebastião e Silva introduced the concepts of the limit of a distribution at a finite point or at infinity and used this to define definite integrals of distributions.  According to his definition (which corresponds in many cases to the usage of theoretical physicists) $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos x dx= 0$. He published a rigorous account in his papers on the axiomatic treatment of distribution theory. A more accessible version is in the text by J. Campos Ferreira "An

Comment: The text mentioned above is entitled "An Introduction to the Theory of Distributions".

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the relevance of this to my comment. In the treatment I mention the space of distributions has a respectable, i.e., Hausdorff, locally convex topology.

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis: as a Lebesgue integral, because the integral of the positive part is infinite and the integral of the negative part is infinite, the overall integral is undefined. $\sin(x)$ is certainly a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$, because it is continuous.

Comment: @CarlMummert we defined a function to be measurable when $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable. And this isn'T the case because it is in both cases not finite

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The assertion that the integral is $0$ doesn't really make sense: the convergence of this improper integral requires that both

\begin{gather}
\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{a}^{0}\sin x \, dx \\
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{0}^{b}\sin x \, dx 
\end{gather}

exist and are finite and neither does. The "break point" $0$ is arbitrary and can be any real number. This is by definition of improper integral, at least the most common definition one finds.

The second limit doesn't exist, because if you compute it on the sequences $2n\pi$ or $2n\pi + \pi/2$ you get different limits:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2n\pi}\sin x \, dx=
\lim_{n\to\infty}[-\cos x]_{0}^{2n\pi}=0
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2n\pi+\pi/2}\sin x \, dx=
\lim_{n\to\infty}[-\cos x]_{0}^{2n\pi+\pi/2}=1
$$

In the same way you show that the first limit doesn't exist (just change the variable with $x=-y$).

Therefore, we can't say that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin x\,dx$ is equal to a number, much less that it's zero, unless we give the symbol some other meaning than an improper integral.

---

If you are considering the principal value, but you should clearly specify it, because it's a different thing than an improper integral, in general, you indeed get $0$, because the sine function is odd: $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$, so, for $a>0$,

$$
\int_{-a}^{a}\sin x\,dx = 0
$$

hence

$$
\mathrm{p.v.}\!\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin x\,dx=
\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}\sin x\,dx = 0
$$

The first equality in the above line is the definition of the principal value integral.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improper integral, so, you have to define it as a limit. You have 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)dx=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^R \sin(x)dx=0.
$$ 
If you now take a different $a$, you have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a+\int_{a}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{-a}+\int_{-a}^{a}+\int_{a}^{R}\sin(x)dx=\int_{-a}^a\sin(x)dx=0 
$$
and nothing changes. Thus, I think that you don't need to split it as $\int_{-\infty}^a+\int_{a}^{\infty}$.

PD: I consider the integral as Principal Value integral (when I pass to the limit the domain is symmetric). See the answer by @egreg

Comment: two comments: 1) the correct way to interpret this improper integral is as two limits, not a single one. 2) I have no idea what the second line of integral is trying to do.

Comment: Use two limits as indicated in the other example. To see this very clearly check $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \,\mathrm{d} x$.

Comment: You can define the integral with only one limit. This is known as Principal value (look the fourth formula in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: With the second line of integrals, you get that the $a$ plays no role for principal value integrals. Otherwise you can't define the limit (as @egreg said).